In Android SDK the build.gradle file continues to throw errors of Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line). what is wrong?
I am trying to build an nfc application that uses biometrics to authorize encryption and decryption. However, I continue to get errors in my build.gradle that prevent my project from building. Below is the code from my build.gradle. Can someone please look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong?
<"""
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.example.nfcencryptionapp"
         minSdk 23
         targetSdk 33
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"

      // Required to use BiometricPrompt
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}

buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-        
              rules.pro'
    }
}

 compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

  kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
}

  dependencies {
           implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
           implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
           implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha04'
           implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nfc:18.0.0'
           implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
 }
 """>

I was trying to build the project, I expected it to pass. However, I received the error: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) instead of the project building.

What's that <""" and """> clutter ?!

I used <""" to ensure there was a clear delineation between my code and my questions
